# Submitting large directories in perforce

Tags: python, unix, perforce

I would like to know unix command to submit large directories in perforce. we use p4 submit to submit files in the depot. But in the case of directories what is the command to put it in depot in a single shot.

Answer (score 1):

It's still just:

```
p4 submit
```

to submit everything open in your default changelist.

If you want to submit all the files under a specific directory, but leave all other files open, do:

```
p4 submit directory/...
```

Comment: And, if that directory's files have never been stored in Perforce before, prior to the `p4 submit` you can do `p4 add directory/...` to mark all those files for add.